# How to programmatically set the GCP Cloud Armor Managed Protection to Plus tier?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-armor

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/GF2ck.png)

I'm trying to write a script (In any language) that demonstrates the clicking of the "CHANGE TO PLUS TIER" button.

I can't find any libraries with commands that do any actions on Cloud Armor GCP.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Armor+ can only be [enabled via the console](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/managed-protection-using#enrolling) at this time. There is no API that you can call to enable the subscription programmatically. You also need to have organization billing privileges.